# How to read entity object in C#

Tags: c#, xml, object, entity

Whenever I try to get a specific value from an object my editor throws the error: `'Object does not contain method for {variable name}'`. Here is my code so far:

```
EntityCollection accounts = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));
            foreach (var c in accounts.Entities)
            {
                var workOrderNum = c.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("wo_workOrderNumber");
                var workOrderCustomer  = c.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("wo_customer");

                # This line succeeds 
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", workOrderNum != null ? (string)workOrderNum.Value : "");
                # This line fails because 'Object does not contain a definition for name'
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", workOrderCustomer != null ? (string)workOrderCustomer.Value.Name : ""); 
            }
```

When I debugged the code I saw that the variable `workOrderCustomer` has a `name` variable within it:
[workOrderCustomer Entity Object.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN33C.png)

Instead of doing `workOrderCustomer.Value.Name` i've tried `workOrderCustomer.Value['Name']`, `workOrderCustomer.Value.['Name']` as well as a few other combinations to no avail. Any idea on how I can get the name variable from the `workOrderCustomer` object?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Here is the documenation to AliasedValue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.aliasedvalue?view=dynamics-general-ce-9

In the example they only use .value though

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I had to cast the object inside the 'AliasedValue' object with the correct object name that allowed me to pull the name variable. In this case it looks like an object 'EntityReference' was inside the 'AliasedValue' object. Here's the line of code that ended up working for me:

```
#'(AliasedValue)c["wo_customer"]).Value' gets the EntityReference Object
var Name = ((EntityReference)((AliasedValue)c["wo_customer"]).Value).Name;
```

Answer (score -2):

a dumb fix would be to simply create a method that return the name in workOrderCustomer and simply call that method in your console writeline

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Do you know what the method would look like? I guess what I am getting at is how do I extract the name variable from workOrderCustomer in the first place.

Comment: I think you have missed what the OP is asking.  They aren't working with standard object types.